# How to bind MudSelect to int[]?

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

```
<MudSelect T="int" @bind-SelectedValues="ViewModel.Model.GlobalSalaryAccessUserIds" MultiSelection="true">
                @foreach (var salaryAccessUser in ViewModel.GlobalSalaryAccessUsers)
                {
                    <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="@salaryAccessUser.Id">@GenerateSalaryAccessUserDisplayString(salaryAccessUser)</MudSelectItem>
                }
            </MudSelect>
```

I want to bind this select to `GlobalSalaryAccessUserIds` which is `int[]`, but I have an error:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<int[]>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'
```

Comment: you need to use generic `EventCallback` type!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define the property `SelectedGlobalSalaryAccessUserIds` as a `IEnumerable`!

```
public IEnumerable<int> SelectedGlobalSalaryAccessUserIds { get; set; } = new List<int>();
```

Comment: It still wouldn't compile.
In addition there's another problem: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int[]>'`

Comment: `MudSelect` component in MudBlazor does not support binding directly to an `int[]` property for multi-selection, but you can work around this limitation by converting the `int[]` property to a `List` property! I'll update my answer!

Comment: It works with `IEnumerable` instead of `List`, but thanks!